How do I create a constructor that would receive different types of parameters?
I have this Point class. I want it to be able to recieve double and SomeType parameters.
Point.pxd:
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr, weak_ptr, make_shared
from SomeType cimport _SomeType, SomeType

cdef extern from "Point.h":
    cdef cppclass _Point:
        _Point(shared_ptr[double] x, shared_ptr[double] y)
        _Point(shared_ptr[double] x, shared_ptr[double] y, shared_ptr[double] z)
        _Point(shared_ptr[_SomeType] x, shared_ptr[_SomeType] y)
        _Point(shared_ptr[_SomeType] x, shared_ptr[_SomeType] y, shared_ptr[_SomeType] z)

        shared_ptr[_SomeType] get_x()
        shared_ptr[_SomeType] get_y()
        shared_ptr[_SomeType] get_z()


cdef class Point:
    cdef shared_ptr[_Point] c_point

Point.pyx:
from Point cimport *

cdef class Point:
    def __cinit__(self, SomeType x=SomeType("0", None), SomeType y=SomeType("0", None), SomeType z=SomeType("0", None)):
        self.c_point = make_shared[_Point](x.thisptr, y.thisptr, z.thisptr)

    def __dealloc(self):
        self.c_point.reset()

    def get_x(self) -> SomeType:
        cdef shared_ptr[_SomeType] result = self.c_point.get().get_x()
        cdef SomeType coord = SomeType("", None, make_with_pointer = True)
        coord.thisptr = result
        return coord

    def get_y(self) -> SomeType:
        cdef shared_ptr[_SomeType] result = self.c_point.get().get_y()
        cdef SomeType coord = SomeType("", None, make_with_pointer = True)
        coord.thisptr = result
        return coord

    def get_z(self) -> SomeType:
        cdef shared_ptr[_SomeType] result = self.c_point.get().get_z()
        cdef SomeType coord = SomeType("", None, make_with_pointer = True)
        coord.thisptr = result
        return coord

    property x:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.get_x()

    property y:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.get_y()

    property z:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.get_z()

How should I write my .pxd and .pyx files so that my Point constructor can receive different type of parameters?

Not specific to Cython, but __init__ should provide one way to initialize the object. Define additional class methods that take other types of arguments and convert them into suitable arguments for __init__.

Please show me. I'm not entirely sure what you mean

For example, def __init__(self, x, y): ..., then @classmethod def from_point(cls, p): return cls(p.x, p.y). Don't overload __init__ to take x, y, and/or a Point.

The one addition to @chepner's comment is: you may prefer to use staticmethod instead since Cython supports cdef staticmethod functions but not cdef classmethod functions. This is relevant if you need to pass types like C pointers. The downside is you lose the benefit of being able to select on cls.

I think I need you guys to just write an answer. It would be easier for me to understand

In Cython, you cannot directly overload constructors (or any methods) as you might in C++ or other languages that support method overloading. However, you can achieve similar functionality by using factory methods or by using Python's flexibility with arguments.
Given your scenario where the Point class needs to accept different types of parameters (either double or SomeType objects), you can implement this flexibility using Python's *args and **kwargs in combination with type checking and processing logic inside the constructor. Additionally, you can define class methods that act as alternative constructors, which is a common Pythonic approach to solve this issue.
Here’s how you might adjust your .pxd and .pyx files to accommodate these requirements:

Point.pxd

This file remains largely the same but ensure it correctly declares everything you need:
# Point.pxd
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr, make_shared
from SomeType cimport _SomeType, SomeType

cdef extern from "Point.h":
    cdef cppclass _Point:
        _Point(shared_ptr[double] x, shared_ptr[double] y)
        _Point(shared_ptr[double] x, shared_ptr[double] y, shared_ptr[double] z)
        _Point(shared_ptr[_SomeType] x, shared_ptr[_SomeType] y)
        _Point(shared_ptr[_SomeType] x, shared_ptr[_SomeType] y, shared_ptr[_SomeType] z)

cdef class Point:
    cdef shared_ptr[_Point] c_point


Point.pyx

Modify this file to include a flexible constructor and additional class methods for different initialisations:
# Point.pyx
from Point cimport *
from libc.stdlib cimport atof

cdef class Point:
    def __cinit__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 2 or len(args) == 3:
            if isinstance(args[0], SomeType):
                ptrs = [arg.thisptr for arg in args]
            else:
                ptrs = [make_shared[double](atof(arg)) for arg in args]
            if len(args) == 2:
                self.c_point = make_shared[_Point](ptrs[0], ptrs[1])
            elif len(args) == 3:
                self.c_point = make_shared[_Point](ptrs[0], ptrs[1], ptrs[2])
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid number of arguments")

    def __dealloc__(self):
        self.c_point.reset()

    @staticmethod
    def from_doubles(x, y, z=None):
        cdef shared_ptr[double] px = make_shared[double](x)
        cdef shared_ptr[double] py = make_shared[double](y)
        cdef shared_ptr[double] pz = make_shared[double](z) if z is not None else None
        if z is None:
            return Point(px, py)
        return Point(px, py, pz)

    # ... rest of the methods ...

Here, __cinit__ accepts variable arguments (*args). It determines the type of each argument and constructs the c_point appropriately, based on the number of arguments and their types. The from_doubles static method provides a clearer, type-specific way to create instances from double values.
This approach gives you the flexibility to initialise Point objects with different types while maintaining clean, readable code. Make sure that the make_shared[double](x) conversions handle input correctly, and adjust the type-checking and conversions as necessary for your specific needs and types.

There's no compelling reason to make from_doubles a static method instead of a class method.

@chepner Thanks for you comment :) I initially made from_doubles a static method because it focuses on creating a new Point object from provided double values without needing any interaction with class properties or the need for handling subclass-specific behaviours. I guess I thought it more about providing a utility function under the Point class's namespace, suitable for being static due to its independence from class instances and properties.  Though on reflection, perhaps you are right !

The code in the constructor won't compile.
